# How to create browser support badges like the ones used in Github?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]

I have used ava.js to do unit testing, and found that I can generate test coverage report in json or html format through nyc.

For browser support I found http://jscc.info/, it shows detailed browser support for APIs I used, but lacking a global browser support.

Are there any libraries that can automatically run browser support test and generate such badges?
Thanks!

Comment: using html, css, and images (or perhaps the right font)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Comment: (By the way, this badge is provided by Sauce Labs)

Comment: they look like **font awesome** glyphs

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figure it out.

The badges are some kind of proves that your code achieves a "standard" or "accomplishment".

So first your code needs to be solid.

For example, these two badges means your code passes the test, and your test coverage rate is 100%.

[image]

Then you can get the badges through running such unit tests on CI services and code coverage services.

And for browser compatability table, you need to write e2e tests that and run on services that provide real browser or application environment.

[image]

Comment: what service do I have to use to get this exact picture for readme in github? can you leave a link pls?